# scanf generates a random number?

Tags: c

Hi I just started C as my first programming language.

I was playing around a bit with `scanf()` and found something strange.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
int main()
{
    int x;

    printf( " Type any number : " );
    scanf( "%d", &x );
    printf( "You entered %d.\n", &x );

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

It always shows me a result of 7 or 8 digit number.

How is it possible?

Comment: You're printing an address (incorrectly). Stop doing that. Turn on your compiler's warnings to the max.

Comment: `printf( "You entered %d.\n", &x );` --> `printf( "You entered %d.\n", x );`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You `printf` `x`'s address instead of value. Fix like this:

```
printf("You entered %d.\n", x);
```

`scanf` wants the address where to store the result, `printf` can take the value itself.

Answer (score 5):

You are printing out the address of x. Remove the '&' before it in the printf and you should see the right thing.
Putting an & before a variable gets a pointer to it - this is necessary in the scanf because it must change the value, but since printf only uses the value, no pointer is needed (except for strings, which are always pointers).

Comment: Actually, putting `&` before a variable takes its *address*. A *pointer* is a type of variable. You could for example take the address of a pointer.